# How do torrent clients seed torrents without loading the entire file into RAM?

Tags: file, bittorrent

How do they access certain blocks of data on HDD/SSDs?I haven't noticed big RAM allocation during torrent downloads.

Comment: How is this specific to torrent clients and not any other software accessing your disk?

Answer (score 0):

You have, programmable, the abillity to seek to a certain position and get x bytes when reading files from the disk. Only this part is in your memory then.